# Rotating a sprite around its center causes size changing

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I have created a class inherited from `Sprite` and added the following function for rotating from center in it:

```
private function rotate(angle:Number):void
        {
            trace(width);

            var tmpWidth:Number = width;
            var rect:Rectangle = getBounds(parent); 
            var matrix:Matrix = transform.matrix;
            matrix.translate(-(rect.left + rect.width/2), -(rect.top + rect.height/2) );
            matrix.rotate((angle/180)*Math.PI); 
            matrix.translate((rect.left + rect.width/2), (rect.top + rect.height/2) );
            transform.matrix = matrix;

            trace(width);
        }
```

My problem is that size of object is changing after rotation. For example, width value before transforming less than width after transforming. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any unexpected behavior.

Since you are applying a rotation, the width and height will likely be different after the rotation.

For instance, if you apply a 90 degree rotation to a 50x100 sprite, it will now be a 100x50 sprite.

If you are performing the rotation on a perfectly square object however, and apply a 90 degree rotation then width before and after should be the same.

Just keep in mind that width and height are calculated based on the bounds of an object. By rotation the object, you likely change the bounds of the object and therefore the width and height.

Comment: The problem is not only with trace output. I can see that the sprite object actually shrinks with every rotation